# Easiest way to get a property name?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How can I get a property's name in as few lines of code as possible?

`myClass.FirstName.ToString()` outputs the value.

How can I get the string value `FirstName` by using this property?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? Expression trees can help.

Comment: I want to add propertyName/value to a Dictionary<string,string>

Comment: see my modified answer.

Comment: Not sure how that will work.  See my comment.

Comment: hi 4thSpace. please check now. It gives result what you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's problem here ? Yes Of Course you can do.

For Example here is your implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PropertiesImpConsoleApp
{
    class Student
    {
        //Declare variables
        string firstname;
        string lastname;

        //Define property for the variables
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstname;
            }
            set
            {
                firstname = value;
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastname;
            }
            set
            {
                lastname = value;
            }
        }
    }
    class MyMain
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student aStudent = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter First Name");
            aStudent.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter LastName");
            aStudent.LastName = Console.ReadLine();

            //And to get the properties names you can do like this
            Dictionary<string, string> aDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            PropertyInfo[] allproperties = aStudent.GetType().GetProperties().ToArray();
            foreach (var aProp in allproperties)
            {
                aDictionary.Add(aProp.Name, aProp.GetValue(aStudent, null).ToString());
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in aDictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",
                pair.Key,
                pair.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

here is another answer using LINQ Expressions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace PropertiesImpConsoleApp2
{
    public static class PropertySupport
    {
        public static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
        {
            if (propertyExpression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
            }

            var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("", "propertyExpression");
            }
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass aMyClass = new MyClass();
            aMyClass.PropertyOne = "Hello";
            Console.WriteLine(PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(() => aMyClass.PropertyOne) + " : " + aMyClass.PropertyOne);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to you get it so key/value are matched?  Right now, you only have key.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Main()
{
  var aType = new { test = "a", test2 = "b" };

  PropertyInfo[] pInfo = aType.GetType().GetProperties();

  foreach(var p in pInfo)
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);

}
```

This will print

```
 test
 test2
```

If you want a Dictionary of the attributes then you should cast it to dynamic which is an object with this feature.

Or maybe you want to be using dynamic to start?  (Sometimes called ExpandoObject).